# How to get data from my ionic capacitor plugin for iOS?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am creating a new ios-plugin with capacitor to ionic 4. I can create the plugin and import to my project but i have a problem with methods on my plugin.

I send someData to my plugin and i hope my method responds a boolean value but that doesn't happen.

PLUGIN IOS

1) .SWIFT

```
lazy var keychain : KeychainSwift = {
    return KeychainSwift()
}()

@objc func setKeychain(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
    let value = call.getString("textToSave") ?? ""
    let identifier = call.getString("identifierOfKey") ?? ""
    var response = false

    if !identifier.isEmpty, !value.isEmpty {
        keychain.set(value, forKey: identifier)
        response = true
    }

    call.resolve([
        "value": response
        ])
}

@objc func setKeychainWithBoolean(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
    let value = call.getString("textToSave") ?? ""
    let identifier = call.getString("identifierOfKey") ?? ""
    var status = call.getBool("status") ?? false

    //if !identifier.isEmpty, !value.isEmpty {
    //    keychain.set(value, forKey: identifier)
    //    status = true
    //}

    status = true

    call.resolve([
        "value": status
        ])
}
```

2) .m

```
CAP_PLUGIN(DanielPlugin, "DanielPlugin",
       CAP_PLUGIN_METHOD(setKeychain, CAPPluginReturnPromise);
       CAP_PLUGIN_METHOD(setKeychainWithBoolean, CAPPluginReturnPromise);
       CAP_PLUGIN_METHOD(echo, CAPPluginReturnPromise);
)
```

3) src/definitions.ts

```
setKeychain(options: { textToSave: string, identifierOfKey: string}): Promise<{value: Object }>;
setKeychainWithBoolean(options: { textToSave: string, identifierOfKey: string , status: boolean }): Promise<{value: Object }>;
echo(options: {value: string}): Promise<{value: string}>;
```

4) src/web.ts

```
async setKeychain(options: { textToSave: string, identifierOfKey: string }): Promise<{value: Object }>{
return Promise.resolve({ value: options.textToSave });}

async setKeychainWithBoolean(options: { textToSave: string, identifierOfKey: string, status: boolean }): Promise<{value: Object }>{
return Promise.resolve({ value: options.status });}

async echo(options: {value: string}): Promise<{value: string}> {
return Promise.resolve({ value: options.value });}
```

IONIC PROJECT

1)

```
onSubmit(){
    this.setObject(); 
  }

  async setObject(){

    const nameValue = this.dataText.get('inputName').value; 

    const data = await DanielPlugin.setKeychain({
      textToSave: nameValue,
      identifierOfKey: 'name'
    });

    const otherData = await DanielPlugin.setKeychainWithBoolean({
      textToSave: nameValue,
      identifierOfKey: 'name',
      status: false
    });

    console.log("json response data:",data);
    console.log("json response otherData:",otherData);
  }
```

On method "setKeychain" i expect the output of "true" or "false" but I get the name I put.

On method "setKeychainWithBoolean" I expect the output "true" but always I have "false"

Plugin -> https://github.com/daniel190392/daniel-plugin-ionic